# TypeError while finding the first matching string from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the URL from the below list, What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> op
[b'key', b'Changes:', b'remote:', b'https://server-1.com/253', b'test', b'change', b'remote:', b'To', b'ssh://server-1:29418/a/ab', b'*', b'[new', b'branch]', b'HEAD', b'->', b'refs/for/foo']
>>>
>>> next(x for x in op if "https" in x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>>
```

Comment: Have you tried b'https'?

Comment: `next(x for x in op if b"https" in x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that all data are returned as bytes objects, not str.

Use `b'some_pattern'` instead of `'some_pattern'`

Answer (score 0):

this list is a list of bytes.
use:

```
next(x for x in op if 'http' in str(x))
```

Comment: Very inefficient.